# String StartsWith() Any Way To Avoid 2 Checks?

Tags: c#

I have this code.  It wasn't obvious at the time, but the code as written is always going to pick the first option since both "fc" and "fcip" start with "fc".

```
string fcportdelimit = "fc";
string fcipportdelimit = "fcip";

if (BlockToProcess[0].StartsWith(fcportdelimit)) 
{
    try
    {
        this.ParseFCInterface(BlockToProcess);
    }
    catch (Exception E)
    {
        throw;
    } 
}
else if (BlockToProcess[0].StartsWith(fcipportdelimit)) 
{
    try
    {
        this.ParseFCIPInterface(BlockToProcess);
    }
    catch (Exception E)
    {
        throw;
    } 
}
```

I looked through the string class but don't see a StartsWith() or Contains() that takes a pattern as input.   The string I am testing against is either going to be a patttern fcN/N or fcipN where N is a number. So, I am thinking I would have to do something like this?

```
if (BlockToProcess[0].StartsWith(fcportdelimit || fcipportdelimit) 
{ 
    if (BlockToProcess[0].StartsWith(fcipportdelimit)
    { 
       // do something here
    } 
    else
    { 
       //since fcipportdelimit didn't match it must be an fcport
       //so do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: `StartsWith(fcportdelimit || fcipportdelimit)` is pretty far from valid syntax...

Comment: Sounds like exactly the sort of problem that Regex's are for. Maybe look into them.

Comment: Have you considered a regular expression match?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that `StartsWith("fcip")` *implies* `StartsWith("fc")`, just test for the latter first and nest the second test.

Furthermore, your `try` blocks are *completely* redundant and serve no function.

```
if (BlockToProcess[0].StartsWith(fcportdelimit) { 
    if (BlockToProcess[0].StartsWith(fcipportdelimit) { 
        // do something here
    }
    else {
        // do something here
    }
}
```

(Of course, the second check still contains a redundant part since it checks for `fc` again but refactoring this check just makes the code less readable and won’t necessarily benefit performance.)

Comment: that's the approach I took.  I didn't want to give up so easily - I thought there might be a method for Strings that I wasn't aware of that would do what I wanted.

Answer (score 7):

I find regular expressions easy. Here is an example with [Regex.IsMatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0.aspx):

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(str, "^(?:fc|fcip)") {
  ...
}
```

The `^` says "anchor to the start" (or, "starts with"), the `|` says "either-or", and the `(?:...)` is for grouping.

However, since each match calls *two different* methods, why not leave it like its? I have removed the extra code to make it simpler to see.

As Konrad points out, the *order* of the conditionals is important.

```
var command = BlockToProcess[0];
if (command.StartsWith("fcip")) {
    this.ParseFCIPInterface(BlockToProcess); // ParseFCIP
} else if (command.StartsWith("fc") {
    this.ParseFCInterface(BlockToProcess);   // ParseFC
}
```

Happy coding.

Comment: But then you *still* need to determine which of those was matched (you *can* use regex for that but your code doesn’t illustrate this). And your second code won’t *ever* use the second branch – you need to reverse the conditionals.

Comment: Why are you using a non-capturing group in the regex? The capture groups are not used for anything here, so it doesn't matter if you put them in the regex.

Comment: @svick Because the regex approach failed to correctly answer the initial question; I covered this bit in the second case. As you point out, the regex could indeed do a capture and then branch inside of it.

Comment: @svick Why not? Normal capture groups for me imply a *declaration of intent* to capture, hence failure to do so in subsequent code imply a possible bug.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I see it the other way around. Since non-capturing groups require “special” syntax, I use capturing groups by default and use non-capturing ones only when I explicitly want to say “I don't want to capture this”.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with making two comparisons, such as this:

```
if (BlockToProcess[0].StartsWith(fcportdelimit) 
    || BlockToProcess[0].StartsWith(fcipportdelimit))
{ 
    if (BlockToProcess[0].StartsWith(fcipportdelimit)
    { 
     // do something here
    } 
    else
    {  //since fcipportdelimit didn't match it must be an fcport
       //so do something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply change it to:

```
if (BlockToProcess[0].StartsWith(fcipportdelimit)) 
{
}
else if (BlockToProcess[0].StartsWith(fcportdelimit)) 
{
}
```

and at least you'll have something that works. Efficiency does not appear to be an issue here.

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
BlockToProcess[0].StartsWith(fcportdelimit) || BlockToProcess[0].StartsWith(fcipportdelimit)
```

Answer (score 0):

> The string I am testing against is either going to be a patttern fcN/N
>   or fcipN

So, logically you only need to make one test. If it doesn't start with "fcip" then it must just start with "fc"

```
string fcipportdelimit = "fcip";
try
{
    if (BlockToProcess[0].StartsWith(fcipportdelimit)) 
    {
        this.ParseFCIPInterface(BlockToProcess);
    } 
    else 
    {
        this.ParseFCInterface(BlockToProcess);
    }
}
catch (Exception E)
{
    throw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is likely overkill but should yield a more maintainable & testable solution.  It will also require some fairly advanced testing & refactoring to keep existing behavior.

The general idea here is that the code you're providing implies that a single parsing class likely knows too much about the individual operations.  Given this, I would initially create an `IParser` interface with two implementations.

```
public interface IParser
{
    void Parse(string input);
    string RequiredPrefix { get; }

    /* you'll want to add anything that's appropriate for your code here */
}

public class FcPortParser : IParser { ... }
public class FcipPortParser : IParser { ... }
```

Then you create a Factory that will return the appropriate parser given input:

```
public class ParserFactory
{
    private List<IParser> _knownParsers;

    public ParserFactory()
    {
        // you should be able to initialize this dynamically but that's off-topic here
        _knownParsers = new List<IParser> { new FcPortParser(), new FcipPortParser() };
    }

    public IParser GetFromString(string given)
    {
        // return the IParser with the longest prefix that given starts with
        // this will return null for a non-match
        return _knownParsers.Where(p => given.StartsWith(p.RequiredPrefix))
                            .OrderByDescending(p => p.RequiredPrefix.Length)
                            .FirstOrDefault();  
    }
}
```

With this solution, you can easily test individual parsers as well as the factory returning the appropriate one.

```
//NUnit
Assert.IsInstanceOf<FcipPortParser>(factory.GetFromString("fcip..."));
Assert.IsInstanceOf<FcPortParser>(factory.GetFromString("fc..."));
Assert.IsNull(factory.GetFromString("undefined..."));
```

... and your code now becomes this:

```
var parser = _factory.GetFromString(BlockToProcess[0]);
if (parser != null)  
{
     parser.Parse(BlockToProcess[0]);
}
```

If you want to avoid the `parser != null` check, you can add a Null Object implementation like this one (and make sure the factory picks it up):

```
public class NullParser : IParser
{
    public void Parse(string given) { /* do nothing */ }
    // should return true for every non-null string
    public string RequiredPrefix { get { return string.Empty; } }
}
```

Now when you need to add functionality, you just add a new IParser class (and, if the factory is not initialized dynamically, the factory).

```
public class FcNewParser : IParser
{
    public void Parse(string given) { ... }
    public string RequiredPrefix { get { return "fcnew"; } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it in reverse order, First check for fcipportdelimit then check for fcportdelimit in else block. That will resolve your problem

```
string fcportdelimit = "fc";
string fcipportdelimit = "fcip";

 if (BlockToProcess[0].StartsWith(fcipportdelimit)) 
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                this.ParseFCInterface(BlockToProcess);
                            }
                            catch (Exception E)
                            {
                                throw;
                            } 
                        }
                        else if (BlockToProcess[0].StartsWith(fcportdelimit)) 
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                this.ParseFCIPInterface(BlockToProcess);
                            }
                            catch (Exception E)
                            {
                                throw;
                            } 
                        }
```